# access violation on ofstream

Tags: c++, c++builder, ofstream

I am using an ofstream to write to a file. I get an access violation when the program closes. If I run the .exe by itself, no errors. I have used ofstream multiple times in other programs and never had a problem.

This is in C++Builder. I have it stripped down to the simplest code:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
  {
  std::ofstream Fred;
  Fred.open("fwe.txt");
  Fred.close();
  }
```

This is the Main Form's constructor. If I just start the program and then exit, without doing anything else, I get the error. When I trace it, it occurs after the Main Form's destructor. I have done all the checks to make sure the open worked and the object is good, they have been removed for clarity.

The creation of the object (no `open()` call ) works. It is in the case that `open()` is called that the program gives the error on exit.  Calling or not calling `close()` makes no difference. I have moved this code to a button, same effect.  If I write to the file, it works fine.

Any ideas? I am stumped.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal compilable sample of code that reproduces the error you mention?

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using? Which STL implementation (RogueWave, STLPort, or Dinkumware)? If you are tracing the code, you should be able to use the debugger to see exactly where the AV is occurring and trace the call stack back to the culprit.

Comment: Builder 5, not sure of the STL version.  The code above generates the error when the program is closed.  Also, if I change ofstream to ifstream, same issue.

Comment: @Mr930 You should still be able to debug shutdown errors with the debugger. In any case, that is a VERY old version of C++Builder. And it used the RogueWave STL, which was replaced with STLPort in C++Builder 6.  RogueWave had its share of problems, so this could very well just be a bug in it (STLPort was later replaced with Dinkumware in C++Builder 2006. Dinkumware is still being used by C++Builder today, with C++Builder 10.4 Sydney about to be released soon).

Comment: I tried stepping through the code after the destructor executed. It went through various system files. I could not determine what the problem was. The odd thing is doing the same thing in other programs with no problems.